# Shoot off email notification when customer's shipping address is updated

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, notifications

The site I'm working on is a wordpress site with Woocommerce installed. I want an email notification to be sent the site admin whenever the shipping address has been updated. Preferably, when a customer updates their own shipping address, a notification informs the store owner by email.

This is what I have right now, but it doesn't appear to be firing off correctly.

```
/* *********************************************** Change of Address Email ***************************************** */
// Send notification email when customer changes address.
  add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_save_address','notify_admin_customer_address_change', 10, 2);
  function notify_admin_customer_address_change( $user_id, $load_address ) {
    // Set the $from_name, $from_email, and $to for your site.
    $from_name = 'Polly Pantry';
    $from_email = 'noreply@pollypantry.com';
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      if (!($current_user instanceof WP_User)) {
       return;
     }

      // format email
      $message .= 'User ' . $current_user->user_login . ' has changed their ' . $load_address .  " address.\n";
      $user_email = $current_user->user_email;
    $message .= 'User Email: ' . $user_email . "\n";
    $message .= 'User First Name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
    $message .= 'User Last Name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
    $message .= "\n";
    $message .= "\n";

    // Get the old address, which as of Woocommerce 3.8, is still in wc()->customer.
    $message .= "Old " . ucfirst($load_address) . " Address:\n";

    switch($load_address) {
      case 'billing':
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . wc()->customer->get_billing_last_name() . "\n";
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_address() . "\n";
        $address_2 = wc()->customer->get_address_2();
        if ($address_2 != '') {
          $message.= $address_2 . "\n";
        }
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_city() . " ";
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_state() . " ";
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_postcode() . "\n";
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_country() . "\n\n";
      break;
      case 'shipping':
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_shipping_first_name() . ' ' . wc()->customer->get_shipping_last_name() . "\n";
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_shipping_address() . "\n";
        $shipping_address_2 = wc()->customer->get_shipping_address_2();
        if ($shipping_address_2 != '') {
          $message .= $shipping_address_2 . "\n";
        }
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_shipping_city() . " ";
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_shipping_state() . " ";
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_shipping_postcode() . "\n";
        $message .= wc()->customer->get_shipping_country();
      break;
    }

    // Get the updated address, which is in the user meta table.
    $message .= "\n\nNew " . ucfirst($load_address) . " Address:\n";

    switch($load_address) {
      case 'billing':
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_first_name', true) . ' ' . get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_last_name', true) . "\n";
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_address_1', true) . "\n";
        $address_2 = get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_address_2', true);
        if ($address_2 != '') {
          $message.= $address_2 . "\n";
        }
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_city', true) . " ";
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_state', true) . " ";
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_postcode', true) . "\n";
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_country', true) . "\n\n";
      break;
      case 'shipping':
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_first_name', true) . ' ' . get_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_last_name', true) . "\n";
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_address_1', true) . "\n";
        $address_2 = get_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_address_2', true);
        if ($address_2 != '') {
          $message.= $address_2 . "\n";
        }
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_city', true) . " ";
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_state', true) . " ";
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_postcode', true) . "\n";
        $message .= get_user_meta($user_id, 'shipping_country', true) . "\n\n";
      break;
    }

    // Set the email up to reply to the user's email.
    $headers = 'From: ' . $from_name . ' <' . $from_email . '>' . "\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $user_email . "\n";

      wp_mail($to, 'Customer Address Change Notice', $message, $headers);
  }
/* **************************************** End of Change of Address Email ***************************************** */
```

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't fire, or did you just not receive a mail? I mean, did you use debug_log or something similar to verify this wasn't called? The code itself looks fine.

Comment: I didn't receive the email. Where would I be able to see outgoing mail logs? I'm not seeing any issues in my debugger.

Comment: @FeliciaSantos I can also confirm that this code is working, maybe check your spam folder or try it with a different email address. A plugin like [E-Mail Log](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/email-log/) allows you to easily log and view all emails sent from WordPress. 
Another option is not to work with emails but to log the event to a dashboard widget in wordpress to name just one..